# BSOD DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE after forced shutdown in Sleep Mode while Applications were Running (possibly the cause)

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bsod, battery

My specs are:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 10.0.18363
- System Modell: E6431 MD60109 Medion x64
- BIOS Version: American Megatrends Inc. 206, 24.06.2016 UEFI
- SMBios Version: 3.0

I've encountered a really bad bug on my Medion Akoya E6431 Laptop:

I think the problems started to appear after the following: I had low battery, that's why my Laptop turned into Battery-Saving mode. After that I didn't used the laptop anymore and it changed into sleep mode while Applications were running etc.. As the battery began to drop under 2 percent, the laptop forced a shutdown on itself and eventually crashed the whole system.

After that event, my Laptop is behaving in a weird way to normal events: I can't open the Network Center in order to connect to the internet or show my Network-Adapters. Furthermore the whole interface for WLAN, LAN etc doesn't work properly on the Taskbar. My Battery-Icon Tray near the Taskbar loads really slow. I can't turn on Battery Saving Mode. If I try to open Task Manager it works but I can't kill the task manager process anymore after that. If I succeed in killing task manager, it will restart the process automatically. Furthermore and the most important one is: If I try to restart/shutdown my computer, it won't work (sometimes I've got a black screen or the restart animation doesn't disappear for more than 2-3 minutes) and if I wait for like 5 minutes a

> DRIVER_STATE_POWER_FAILURE or
>   DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (I'm not sure which one)

will appear, which opens a helper menu to restart the computer in 10 seconds. After that the computer won't restart and goes into Black-Screen and I have to force shutdown.

I tried to uninstall network drivers in order to fix the WLAN issue with no internet, but I noticed that when I want to uninstall the driver (I don't remember the name correctly, something with PPPOE - the internet protocol) it wouldn't work and an infinite loop appears where the system tries to uninstall that specific driver, all other network drivers could be uninstalled tho. After that I needed to force a restart again, because it never stopped again for like 30 minutes. Unfortunately it got worse after the boot up: Now Cortana Search, Network-Icon-Tray on the Taskbar, Battery Icon Tray on the Taskbar lead to a freeze of the whole system where the cursor indicates that something is loading. Windows Explorer, Google Chrome etc. are working properly.

I really need my Laptop for my upcoming exams and stuff like that. I would be glad if you could help me.

What should I do in order to fix the problems? Fresh restart? Complete wipe of all data? Is the problem software-only or may my harddrive got damaged too/or data got erased?

Edit: I've also tried to repair broken system files with the command `sfc /scannow` in the terminal, which indeed found broken files and repaired them successfully, but it had no impact...

Sry for the bad layout and spelling mistakes, I'm currently writing this over my mobile device. It's kinda hard to do so.

Comment: Hard shutdown while sleeping is most likely the cause.

Comment: What should I do in order to fix the problems? Fresh restart? Complete wipe of all data? Is the problem software-only or may my harddrive got damaged too/or data got erased?